# What is Api.http file in .NET 8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Recently I have installed .NET 8 and created the asp.net core project. The project structure is same just like .NET 7 but I don't know what is this Api.http file in this version.

I have searched online and found out that this file will be used to test the api endpoints but how ?

Comment: [Genuine question: please don't be offended] Why is it downvoted? I was using .Net 6 till yesterday. Today with new project I also saw this file and the first link in the google to address my curiosity was this SO question. I understand that I should go to MSDN or .Net blogs for this, but if google takes me here won't it be good for SO only?
If I see it downvoted I assume its not related to .http of .NET 8 and go away from SO site...

Comment: Very easy to understand video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU8Bu1fc3_0&ab_channel=NickChapsas

Comment: @deathrace - Downvoting is not an indication that the question is not related to one of it tag's. Please hover over the downvote button: "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature provided by Visual Studio 2022 for testing ASP.NET Core projects, particularly API applications. This file serves as a convenient way to send HTTP requests and view responses directly within Visual Studio.

The Visual Studio 2022 ".http" file editor allows you to create and update ".http" files within your project. These files can be used to define HTTP requests that you want to send to your API endpoints.

Within the ".http" file, you can specify the details of HTTP requests such as the URL, HTTP method **(GET, POST, etc.)**, **headers, query parameters, request body,** etc.

After sending a request from the ".http" file, Visual Studio displays the response directly within the editor. This allows you to view the response status code, headers, and body, making it easy to debug and test your API endpoints.

You can also check the completed Microsoft official documentation of using http files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/http-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0